# How do I make this page auto resize in most browsers and resolutions?

Tags: html, css

I know this question was given a -1 but if you look at the code you will see I have been working hard on this page, I just can't make the resizing work.

I have tried a few different techniques, both css and html and nothing seems to work, could someone show me how to do this? The page is for teaching 5 and 6 year olds to read and we want it to fit within a browser window at most resolutions with out  scroll bars. I'm including some code as it would not allow me to post with out it, please refer to the codepen link for the actual code.
[This is the code here, the actual functionality of the page doesn't work at code pen, that isn't an issue, the page does what it is supposed to if you test it locally.](https://codepen.io/redtailmedia/pen/vXBPWP)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        html{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
body{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    
}
        .main-grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            grid-gap: 3rem;
            max-width: 50rem;
        }

        .container-single-letters {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 2em);
            gap: 10px;
        }

        .container-consonant-teams {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 3em);
            gap: 10px;
        }

        .consonant-teams-header {
            grid-column-start: 1;
            grid-column-end: 8;
            grid-row-start: 1;
            grid-row-end: 1;

            background-color: lightcoral;
            font-size: x-large;
            padding: .5em;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .vowel-teams-row {
            grid-column-start: 1;
            grid-column-end: 3;
            grid-row-start: 2;
            grid-row-end: 2;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .vowel-teams-header {
            background-color: lightgray;
            font-size: x-large;
            padding: .5em;
        }

        .vowel-teams-table,
        td {
            border: gray 1px solid;
            text-align: center;
            border-collapse: collapse;

            font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 1.0rem;
            letter-spacing: 0.2em;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: center;

            max-width: 100%;
            table-layout: fixed;

            grid-column-start: 1;
            grid-column-end: 3;
            grid-row-start: 3;
            grid-row-end: 3;

            padding: 0.5rem;
        }

        .vowel-teams-sound {
            border: 1px solid red;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: .5em;
            padding: 5px;
            cursor: move;
            font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 1.0em;
            letter-spacing: 0.2em;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .vowel-team {
            cursor: move;
            font-size: 1.0em;
        }

        .sounds-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 5em repeat(13, 4em);
            gap: 2px;

            grid-column-start: 1;
            grid-column-end: 3;
            grid-row-start: 4;
            grid-row-end: 4;
        }

        .sounds-header {
            font-size: x-large;
            vertical-align: middle;
            align-content: center;
        }

        .sounds-box {
            border: 3px solid cornflowerblue;
            background-color: #ddd;
            border-radius: .5em;
            padding: 3px;
            font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: .9em;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .sounds-box.over {
            border: 3px dotted cornflowerblue;
        }

        .box {
            border: 3px solid #666;
            background-color: #ddd;
            border-radius: .5em;
            padding: 5px;
            cursor: move;
            font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 1.0em;
            letter-spacing: 0.2em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .conbox {
            border: 3px solid #008000;
            background-color: #FFD300;
            border-radius: .5em;
            padding: 5px;
            cursor: move;
            font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 1.0em;
            letter-spacing: 0.2em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .vowlbox {
            border: 3px solid #666;
            background-color: #ddd;
            border-radius: .5em;
            padding: 5px;
            cursor: move;
            font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 1.0em;
            letter-spacing: 0.2em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .blueconbox {
            border: 3px solid blue;
            background-color: #FFD300;
            border-radius: .5em;
            padding: 5px;
            cursor: move;
            font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 1.0em;
            letter-spacing: 0.2em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .vowlgreybox {
            color: red;
            border: 0px solid #666;
            background-color: lightgray;
            border-radius: .5em;
            padding: 3px;
            cursor: move;
            font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: x-large;
            letter-spacing: 0.2em;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

after  html tag  and The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

source https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: I added it but I'm still getting scroll bars and no change in size of the elements on browser resize.